# PHP messes with percent % sign

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])){
$user = $_POST['user'];
}
else
{
$user = "%%";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '$user'";
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

causes the query not work, because echo is:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ''
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%%'
```

how can this be fixed?

Comment: First off, your code is *extremely* vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For the sake of your users, please use parameterized queries. See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) if the user is there.

Comment: `$POST['user']` is set, but empty... `if(isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user'])){`

Comment: MightyPork it says ["user"]=>string(0)

Comment: p.s.w.g  injection in select? how... and the user-post comes from a drop-down list. And your link, sorry...i dont use the arrow-php, i use the basic one.

Comment: It's possible that malicious hackers are not willing to use your drop-down list and prefer to enter their own values.

Comment: i dont understand what injection can do?? select something else or what?

Comment: Depending on the back-end code and database, things like stealing credit cards, impersonating other users, deleting your database... But nothing really serious as hurting dogs, I guess.

Comment: oh..how can you ENTER something in a LIST?...its there its not a textfield, its the <select> input type?

Comment: but you need permission for this? dont you?

Comment: You can can submit **anything** to a remote server: `<form action="http://your.server.example.com/your-form.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="ultra-secure-inmutable-numeric-only-list" value="Oranges!"></form>`

Comment: Also, no need to have two percentage signs, `$user = "%%";`, if you which to get hits on all. Try `$user = "%";`.

Answer (score 1):

I would think, your $_POST['user'] is set, and filled with ''.